# Tratar CSV con un JSON en su interior con Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

Os comento. Tengo un archivo CSV con varias columnas. Lo que quiero es importar el archivo con Pandas mediante pd.read_csv.

Hasta aquí no hay ningún problema.

Sin embargo, el archivo, contiene en una de sus columnas (la última) un JSON. Sucede que al importar el CSV la última columna no la lee bien.

Lo que necesito es poder importar el CSV, que lea correctamente cada columna y que el JSON que está en la última columna se divida en distintas columnas también para poder tratarlo todo como un dataframe.

Consideraciones:

1. Los campos del JSON no tienen cabecera (no me importa, puedo estar sin cabecera)
2. No en todas las líneas del CSV la columna con el JSON contiene los mismos campos; puede haber diferencias, pero necesito que la importación se realice de forma ordenada. Es decir, que haya coherencia en el contenido de cada columna en cada fila (si una columna de las que se generan con el JSON habla de X, que en todas las filas haya valores de X, y si alguna fila no contiene dicha información, que esté vacía, por ejemplo).

No puedo poner fragmentos de mi código porque, simplemente, no sé como hacer frente a esta situación. He buscado pero no sé como tratar un CSV con un JSON en una columna.

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias de antemano,

Un saludo,

Comment: Podrias poner una muestra de tu csv y un [emcv](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) o una lista de algunos de los links visitados por favor. Asi, sera posible ayudarte y demostrarás que de veras te esforzaste.

Comment: Estoy muy interesado en ese escenario, no quiero que quede en nada.

Comment: O sea, quieres que los datos de la cadena JSON sean parte de los datos de la misma tabla. ¿Cada clave se correspondería con una columna? Porque no logro entender el escenario planteado.

Comment: El problema es que no sé ni por dónde comenzar. He importado como un CSV y en la columna que contiene un JSON no aparece nada. He buscado por internet pero no sé como avanzar ni cómo proceder. Ojalá pudiese compartir algo de código, pero no sé cómo avanzar con esto...

Comment: *he buscado por internet* pues, que links has visitado? Hay mas formas de demostrar tu esfuerzo. Y esa que dije parece ser la mas adecuada nwn Por cierto, no olvides poner una muestra de tu csv para conocer de que modo esta incrustado el json.

Comment: Buen día @Deshume, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo puedes hacer fácilmente con [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

Como no agregaste algunas filas de tu `dataframe` hice un ejemplo genérico:

```
import pandas as pd

# Diccionarios para ejemplificar los json
d1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
d2 = {'c': 30, 'd': 40}

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,2,3,4,5],
                   'B': [d1, d2, d1, d2, d1, d2]}) 

# Dataframe original
print(df)

# Normalizar la columna "B" en el eje 1 (axi = 1), es decir, esto agrega columnas
# Concatenamos las nuevas columnas en el dataframe original
# Eliminamos la columna "B" (Esto es opcional, se puede quitar si se desea conservar la columna "B")
df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df['B'])], axis=1).drop(columns = ['B'])

# Dataframe modificado
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve lo siguiente:

```
# Dataframe original
   A                   B
0  0  {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
1  1  {'c': 30, 'd': 40}
2  2  {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
3  3  {'c': 30, 'd': 40}
4  4  {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
5  5  {'c': 30, 'd': 40}

# Dataframe modificado
   A     a     b     c     d
0  0  10.0  20.0   NaN   NaN
1  1   NaN   NaN  30.0  40.0
2  2  10.0  20.0   NaN   NaN
3  3   NaN   NaN  30.0  40.0
4  4  10.0  20.0   NaN   NaN
5  5   NaN   NaN  30.0  40.0
```